# boto IAM: Getting a policy template

Tags: amazon-web-services, boto

I am trying to create a new group with permissions based on a policy template. When creating a new group in the AWS console, there is a list of policy template to base the group permissions on. How can I replicate this behavior in boto?

I have:

```
import boto.iam as botoi
iam_1 = botoi.IAMConnection()
iam_1.create_group("group1")
iam_1.put_group_policy(groupname = "group1", policy_name="???")
```

Is there a way to get a list of all the policy templates, and the JSON corresponding to them, so that I can pass that back to `put_group_policy`?

Thanks.

### Edit

Here is an example of what the group policy setup on AWS console looks like:
[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "policy template".  Do you mean a managed policy?

Comment: @garnaat Updated with an image of what it looks like in the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to create an IAM Group and then attach an existing IAM Managed Policy to that group.  The IAM service does provide a way to get a listing of all existing Managed Policies but unfortunately that capability has not yet been added to boto.

There is a pending [pull request](https://github.com/boto/boto/pull/3185) and it looks like it is close to being merged.  If that gets merged, you would be able to do this:

```
import boto
iam = boto.connect_iam()
managed_policies = iam.list_policies(scope='AWS')
```

to get a listing of all AWS policies.

Comment: `boto3` appears to have an `attach_group_policy` that should do this. Can you help understand [the specification of the ARN of managed policies](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/policies_managed-controlling-access-to.html#policies-specifying-policy-arn)?

Comment: I got it working with `boto3`. The ARN for the managed policy `PowerUserAccess` is specified as `"arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/PowerUserAccess"`.

Comment: Yes, boto3 has full support and is always up to date with the latest features and services.